# Page Not Found when clicking on non-existant tag in chat room

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-bydesign, chat

In the Ask a Super User Moderator chat room, when someone clicks on [tag:moderator*](https://superuser.com/tags/moderator*/info), a page not found error is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: I removed the tag from the chat room.

This is expected behavior. There is no [moderator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/moderator) or `moderator-*` tag on Super User, so naturally there is no tag wiki for it. I'm not sure why the tag was added in the first place, but I've since removed it so it won't be a problem any more.

Comment: Thanks, why would someone downvote my question?

Comment: Who knows? The downvote arrow says `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`. I would expect that somebody else saw this post and thought it fit one of those categories. Votes on Meta don't affect your reputation anyways, so I wouldn't worry about it.